# Differences in JWT Token Body between @azure/msal-browser and microsoft-adal-angular6 Libraries in Angular 15

Tags: angular, azure, jwt

I'm encountering an issue with JWT token generation using different Angular libraries for Azure AD authentication.

To provide a background, we have an legacy angular app using java api in backend which are behind apigee proxy & requires valid access token from apigee. Front end angular uses microsoft-adal-angular6 library to generate id token from azure & it passed to "token" endpoint in apigee to generate access token. "token" endpoint has policies to validate the jwt token. This app is working fine.

Our new application is built on Angular 15, initially used the @azure/msal-browser library (recommended library) for authentication, but we faced challenges with the generated token when interacting with an Apigee proxy.

To troubleshoot, we temporarily switched to the legacy microsoft-adal-angular6 library, which resolved the issue. However, upon inspecting the JWT tokens generated by both libraries, we noticed differences in the token body properties. It's worth noting that we utilized the same app registration for both libraries.

Is it expected for the JWT token body to differ when using distinct libraries for token generation? The minor difference in both approaches was the response type for the authorize endpoint is 'id_token' for the old library and 'code' for the new library due to changes in support. Could this discrepancy be a contributing factor to the differences observed in the token body?

Any insights or suggestions on how to align the token generation between these libraries for consistent behavior would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The differences in JWT token body properties between the libraries are likely due to variations in their implementations and configurations. The change in response type (from 'id_token' to 'code') could contribute to this. To align token generation, ensure consistent configuration, compliance with standards, and consider customizing the libraries if needed. Testing and validation are crucial for ensuring compatibility with your application and external systems.

Comment: For configuration of both the libraries, we require client id, tenant id, response type & scopes. I believe scope would change the access token but Id token should be same in both cases because I am using the same app in azure portal. Are you confirming if I use different libraries, I might get different type of id token even with same configuration? What will happen when old libraries goes out of scope?

Comment: Yes, different libraries may generate slightly different ID tokens even with the same configuration. When old libraries become deprecated, it's essential to migrate to newer ones to ensure ongoing support and compatibility with evolving standards and best practices.

Comment: Ok. I assumed token is generated by IdP & hence the token body should be same no matter which library is used.